# Can I change glass transition temperature (Tg) and impact resistance with additives?

Tags: polymers

I have three different HDPE polymers with different melting index but they don't have any elasticity. Physical form of polymers is granules. Can I change glass transition temperature (Tg) and impact resistance with additives?

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.se! If you have questions about how to beautify your posts, have a look at the [help]. Do you want to know more about this site, please take the [tour].

Comment: No. Buy a suitable Polyethylene.

Answer (score 1):

The glass transition temperature depends on the cooling rate and molecular weight distribution and **could be influenced by additives**:

Most liquid plasticizers are low molecular weight organic materials with a glass transition temperature in the range of $125-225^0\text{C}$. When this kind of additives is added to an organic polymer, the result is a weight averaging of the glass transition temperature between that of the polymer and that of the plasticiser if they are miscible. The reduction of the the glass transition temperature of a polymer by the plasticiser is usually about   $5^0\text{C}$ per weight percent of plasticiser.

Impact modifiers ( a kind of additives) can affect the impact resistance of a polymer. Impact modifiers are key additives for
increasing flexibility and impact strength
to meet physical property requirements of
rigid polymers. All impact modifiers are elastomeric or
rubbery in nature, with a lower modulus
than the host polymer. The dispersed
rubber phase acts to absorb or dissipate the
energy of impact in order to stop craze or
crack propagation.

Comment: Plasticisers don't work in PE, because they do not dissolve. You could try blending with some low Mw LDPE.